# How to trim off the query part of a url using javascript alone?

Tags: javascript, url

I've scowerd stackoverflow & for some reason this question is simply not answered in a clear enough manner for me to get right..

I have a url pathname www.thisurl.com/this/url/is/generic%877948

I want to console log the url alone, trimming off the query part of so that all I get is: www.thisurl.com.

I've tried the following:

```
var pathtotrim = location.href.split('/').pop();
document.write(pathtotrim);
console.log("hello", pathtotrim);
```

But this trims off the beginning of the url leaving me with /this/url/is/generic%877948.

Essentially doing the opposite of what I want. How can I trim off the query part of a url to be console logged.. please!!!???

Comment: have you tried with just location.host?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var pathtotrim = location.href.split('/')[0];
```

This will split the string on the `/` but will take the first segment (in your case that would be www.x.com)

Edit: 
Like [Leilo Faieta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2399035/lelio-faieta) Said, `location.host` or `location.hostname` would be quicker.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var pathtotrim = "www.thisurl.com/this/url/is/generic%877948".split('/')[0];
document.write(pathtotrim);
console.log("hello", pathtotrim);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to manipulate strings: you can just use `location.host` or `location.hostname.`
This will give you the www part of the url.

on this url:

> `https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&source=hp&ei=P9SXW7_RO9CKmgWiybjIBA&q=location&oq=location&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j0i131k1j0l8.269799.273393.0.273746.20.13.4.1.1.0.156.1198.8j4.13.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..2.18.1341.6..35i39k1j0i10k1.98.Zbh8pzpSLkY`

you will get

> www.google.com

If you want to have all the first part of the url including the http protocol

```
location.protocol + '//' + location.host
```

on the same example url you will get

> `https://www.google.com`

Answer (score 0):

```js
let url = 'www.thisurl.com/this/url/is/generic%877948'
console.log(url.replace(/\/.*/g, ''));
```